# How do I solve $\int_{-1}^1 xe^{-x^4}dx $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I know from the answers that its 0, but I cant figure out why.

When i put $\int xe^{-x^4}dx $ in a calculator website i get erf.

I tried integrating in parts, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There are now multiple answers using the fact that the integrand is odd. It's worth noting one should also check $\int_0^1x\exp(-x^4)dx$ is finite, with e.g. $0\le x\exp(-x^4)\le x$ on $[0,\,1]$.

Comment: @J.G. ... Indeed, any answer that does not remark that the integral converges (perhaps by saying that $x=0$ is a removable discontinuity) must be considered incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is odd so

$$\int_{-1}^1 xe^{-x^4}dx = 0$$

with no antiderivative needed.

Comment: So ill have to show f(x) = f(-x)* ? where f(x) is the function we integrate?

Comment: @Aaron The integrand $f$ is such that $f(x)=-f(-x);$ in other words, it is odd.

Comment: @ryang and f(x) would be the function we integrate, correct?

Comment: @Aaron Correct. The [integrand](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Integrand.html) $f(x)=x\exp x^4$ is of the form $xg(x^2)$, so it has to be odd.

Comment: Sorry, $x\exp-x^4$.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in the comments, the integral of an odd function on the interval $[-a,a]$ is zero. You can check this with a simple change of variable:
$$
\int_{-a}^0 f(x) dx \underbrace{=}_{y=-x} \int_{a}^0 (-1)f(-y) \,dy = \int_0^a f(-y) dy = \int_0^a -f(y) dy \left(= -\int_0^a f(x) \,dx \right).
$$

So,

$$
\int_{-a}^a f(x)\, dx = \int_{-a}^0 f(x) \,dx + \int_0^a f(x) \,dx = -\int_0^a f(x) \,dx + \int_0^a f(x) \,dx = 0
$$

Comment: Would you generalise $[-1,1]$ to $[a,a]\,?$ If you ping me, I'll be able to upvote.

Comment: @ryang Sure... I just used the $[-1,1]$ interval to stay closer to the specific question. I'll edit.

Comment: @amWhy Although I agree that the question is not phrased in the best way, it does show that the OP honestly tried  to solve the problem. This is not the typical "solve this for me" question.